# p value correlation for random vectors in R

Tags: r, correlation

I want to calculate correlation coefficient between random vectors and use this for hypothesis testing. The code

```
bs <- function(qtS, rvNum = 1000)
{
  eb <- qtS * rvNum
  randVect <- matrix(rnorm(eb), nrow=qtS, ncol = rvNum)
  randVect <- randVect/sqrt(sum(randVect * randVect))
  randVectCor <- cor(randVect)
  randVectCor <- randVectCor[col(randVectCor) < row(randVectCor)]
  plot(density(randVectCor), main = "resampled data density distribution", type = "l", lwd  = 2, xlim = c(min(randVectCor), max(randVectCor)))
  list(min = min(randVectCor), max = max(randVectCor), randVectCor = randVectCor)
}
```

works well but with one peculiar thing that I argue a lot with my colleague. Namely, if the qtS is small (i.e. 5) then the max and min are higer than 0.99 which in turn leads to rejection of the vast majority of possible observed correlation values. But with increasing qtS min and max values get lower and with i.e. 50 this value is 0.6. Is this OK, I mean the fact that possible correlations between vectors with fewer elements are orderly larger than between vectors with greater number of elements?

Comment: I don't think you can use correlations as the basis for hypothesis testing.  Instead, you should fit a linear model and compare the F-score with the critical F-statistic.  The F-test will automatically penalise small sample sizes (because of low number of degrees of freedom).

Comment: This question is off topic for SO (see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)). You'll probably find more answers at http://www.crossvalidated.com. No need to crosspost, I flagged your question for moderator attention, so it will probably be migrated to there pretty soon.

Comment: @Andrie you should be able to use any statistic for hypothesis testing if you can come up with a suitable distribution for it... which I think is what Ian's code is doing but I'm having a hard time following it... Ian could you maybe explain in words how your code works (at least for my benefit)?

Comment: Why not use `cor.test`?  It's good that you're using simulations to learn about how these quantities vary. (Heck, that's what Student did back in 1907 [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Sealy_Gosset]). But also know that there are a lot of reliable inferential tools already out there!  Good luck.

Comment: @owen the randVect is a matrix of random numbers that has the length of qtS * rvNum, which is right after its declaration normalized to a unit length. Then a correlation matrix and its lower triangle are used for generating the distribution of possible correlations. For a possible significance test with this look at my comment down below. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely fine, and to be expected.

In fact, when testing the correlation between vectors of length two, the correlation can only take values of 0, 1, or -1  (and will only have value of 0 when one of the vectors has no variance).

Try a few simulations to see this:

```
> set.seed(44)
> cor(rnorm(2), rnorm(2))
[1] -1
> cor(rnorm(2), rnorm(2))
[1] 1
> cor(rnorm(2), rnorm(2))
[1] -1
```

A straight line can perfectly fit any two points in the plane: the points thus exhibit a perfect linear dependence --- the definition of a Pearson correlation coefficient of 1 (or -1). Furthermore, it's not too unlikely that three random points on a plane will fall approximately along a line, resulting in a large correlation, but a million points (or even 10 or 20) rarely will. The expected absolute correlation coefficient for random points thus declines with increasing sample size.

Comment: Of course that is the case, as I was telling to my colleague. But I have some correlation statistic between two vectors from the real data and it is i.e. 0.72. How can I use the mentioned function if I want to test this number against the distribution of corr coefficients between two random vectors. If they have let`s say 5 elements then I will never get the significant result...In fact this is all about random Skewers method from one of my previous posts and testing its sig...

Comment: Just do something like (for this made-up data) `cor.test(1:5, c(1,2,3,4,3)`. This example has a correlation coefficient of 0.832, but its p-value is 0.081. So clearly a sample correlation coefficient of 0.72 is simply not significant if it's based on just 5 samples. If the correlation is real, you'll likely need more data (more points) to demonstrate that.